# Trying to get excel 2003 into already made windows form

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, excel-2003

What my problem is is that I have a project that is in full design mode swing right now. I built it using the Windows form..

Anyways, on one of my forms..that I already started building (very painstakingly)..
Minds have changed and now what needs to be on that form is either a full excel 2003 workbook..or at the very least..excel worksheet.

The problem is that I have not been using studio 2008 for long..and coding experience shows the same.

Can someone please tell me how the heck I can put a worksheet or a workbook on that form without starting my whole project over using office forms?

Please..go slow with this newbie because i really don't know anything and Jargon is confusing me even more :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

http://www.codeproject.com/kb/office/Embedding_Excel.aspx